# Trimming text from a multi-line entry in postgres with regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, trim

I have a column "verbatim" where each entry contains multiple lines. Here's an example:

```
Dummy field1:Text

Tell Us More:Text to capture

Dummy field2:Text
```

I'd like to capture only `Text to capture` text in the second line `Tell Us More:` and put that value into the column `verbatim_scrubbed`. In the example above, `Text to capture` would be the entry in `verbatim_scrubbed`.

I'm not that great with postgres and `regexp`, so I was hoping somebody could help me out here. Was thinking of something similar to the following:

```
update TABLE
set verbatim_trimmed = array_to_string(regexp_matches(verbatim,'tell us more:(.*)','gi'));
```

This doesn't work, but I have a feeling something similar may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a direct way to capture the: `Text to capture` without the cariage return `\r` and the new line `\n` charracters (without using the [regexp_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)).

Here is what you can do:

```
select regexp_replace(array_to_string(regexp_matches(verbatim, '^Tell Us More:(.*)$','n'),'',''), E'[\\r\\n]', '' ) from my_table;
```

Comment: Thanks Houari. This is exactly what I needed! Apologies for the late response -- was traveling during the weekend.